# Windows Live SDK getting user's email (WP7)

Tags: windows, sdk, live

I need help on getting user's email. I've been trying to figure out how to get user's personal email and I'm still unable to get it.

Here's part of my code:

```
string id = e.Result.ContainsKey("id") ? e.Result["id"] as string : string.Empty;
string birth_day = e.Result.ContainsKey("birth_day") ? e.Result["birth_day"] as string :    string.Empty;
string birth_month = e.Result.ContainsKey("birth_month") ? e.Result["birth_month"] as    string : string.Empty;
string birth_year = e.Result.ContainsKey("birth_year") ? e.Result["birth_year"] as string : string.Empty;
```

//testing

```
string personal = e.Result.ContainsKey("emails.personal") ? e.Result["emails.personal"] as string : string.Empty;
string preferred = e.Result.ContainsKey("emails.preferred") ? e.Result["emails.preferred"] as string : string.Empty;
```